# many-to-many query

Tags: sql, many-to-many

I have following database structure,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `analyze` (
  `disease_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `symptom_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `disease` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `symptom` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ;
```

**EDIT:**
Sorry, I mean how do I identify the disease from inputted symptoms.
Example:
If I have symptom: fever and cough then I would have influenza.
If I have symptom: sore throat and fever then I would have throat infection.
The input are `$symptom1`, `$symptom2`, `$symptom3`, and so on.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT disease_id
FROM analyze
GROUP BY disease_id
HAVING COUNT(symptom_id) > 1
```

Edit: to reply to the edited question

```
SELECT disease_id, COUNT(DISTINCT symptom_id)
FROM analyze
WHERE symptom_id IN ($symptom1, $symptom2, $symptom3)
GROUP BY disease_id
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT symptom_id) DESC
```

Of course you'll have to replace `$symptomX` by their respective ID's.

This query lists the diseases which match *at least* one symptom - the diseases which match the most symptoms are on top.

If you added an unique constraint on `symptom`_id and `disease_id` in `analyze`, you could lose the `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT disease_id, COUNT(symptom_id)
FROM analyze
WHERE symptom_id IN ($symptom1, $symptom2, $symptom3)
GROUP BY disease_id
ORDER BY COUNT(symptom_id) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select d.id from disease d inner join analyze a
    on d.id = a.disease_id
    group by d.id having count(a.disease_id) > 1
```

Comment: you might want to add d.name too in the query (and group by)

Answer (score 0):

```
select disease_id, count(*)
from analyze
where symptom_id in ($symptom1, $symptom2, $symptom3)
group by disease_id 
order by 2 descending;
```

will return the matching disease ids in descending order of matching symptoms.